# sharing data between two popups at Android

Tags: android, popup

I have a `popup` on my app that opens another one *without closing* itself. The thing is I want to put some data at the second `popup`, close it, and load the data on the first one. This is my code:

```
popup.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() 
        { 
            public void onDismiss() 
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_pagocontarjeta);
                tv.setText(((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.calc_tv)).getText());
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work, I get a **`NullPointerException`** at the line:

**`tv.setText(((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.calc_tv)).getText());`**.

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: show your logcat, xml, and complete activity code

Comment: I've fixed this, I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_pagocontarjeta);
```

use

```
TextView tv = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_pagocontarjeta);
```

Comment: Doesn't works, layout value is assigned to other popup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it's worked:

```
popup.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() 
    { 
        public void onDismiss() 
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_pagocontarjeta);
            tv.setText(((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.calc_tv)).getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by creating an static variable of the popups:

```
static View popup_forpag;
static View popup_buscadorgenerico;
```

and then I've inflated the popup from them:

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.dim_bg);
    fl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final Activity context = Activity_Mesas.this;

    // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.Buscador_Generico);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popup_buscadorgenerico = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.buscador_generico, viewGroup);

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(popup_buscadorgenerico);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    popup.setWidth((int) (width*0.8));
    popup.setHeight((int) (height*0.8));
    popup.setFocusable(true);

    // Clear the default translucent background
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

    // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
    popup.showAtLocation(popup_buscadorgenerico, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

finally:

```
popup.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() 
    { 
        public void onDismiss() 
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)popup_forpag.findViewById(R.id.tv_pagocontarjeta);
            tv.setText(((TextView)popup_buscadorgenerico.findViewById(R.id.calc_tv)).getText());
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your answers.